# VS Code "Start without debugging" stopped working

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

As of today my VS Code (ver. 1.69.1) started acting funny.
Yesterday I could open a python script, click "Run without debugging" and the script would run fine.
Today, every time I try to run the script I get no output in the terminal and the start stop relaunch toolbar at the top appears for just a second before disappearing.
As I said, I get no messages, no errors or warnings. Has anyone experienced this too?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Same experience. A regular PC restart didn't help. Then I turned off the PC and after turning it on the problem disappeared! I don't know, I felt like a shaman.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! Unfortunately I tried that multiple times now, but nothing has changed. Any more ideas?

Comment: One more thing comes to mind: I noticed that when running debug, there is a reference to Python extension version 2022.8.0 in the command line. But the last VSCode update installed the new version 2022.10.1. I rolled back version 2022.8.0 (in VSCode section Extensions (Ctrl+Shift+X)/ Python / Uninstall menu / Install Another Version...). This didn't help immediately, but after restarting the PC a few times and finally shutting it down, the debugging started working again.

Comment: But I recommend finding out which version of the Python extension is required for you.